# Player spazzes all over the area when doubled clicked

Tags: actionscript-3

When the player is doubled clicked, he spazzes around the map. How do I prevent this?

This is the code I'm using to control the player:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickReaction);  
// speeds ALONG NYPOTENUSE  
var v:Number = 7;  
// vector of movement  
var dir:int = 100;  
// mouse click point  
var clickPoint:Point = new Point();  
// angle doesn't change metween clicks - so it can be global  
var angle:Number;  

function myClickReaction (e:MouseEvent):void {   
     clickPoint = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);  
     angle = Math.atan2(clickPoint.y - penguin.y, clickPoint.x - penguin.x);  
     dir = angle >= 0 ? -1 : 1;  
     addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);  
}  

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {  
     var projectedX:Number = penguin.x + v * Math.cos(angle);  
     var projectedY:Number = penguin.y + v * Math.sin(angle);  
     var diff:Number = clickPoint.y - projectedY;  
     if (diff / Math.abs(diff) == dir) {  
          penguin.x = clickPoint.x;  
          penguin.y = clickPoint.y;  
          removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);  
     }  
     else {  
          penguin.x = projectedX;  
          penguin.y = projectedY;  
     }  
}
```

Comment: The problem is, this code does not control if the player is already in motion when click happens, so it just applies second (third and so on) motion without cancelling the current one.

Comment: How do I prevent this?

Comment: Cancel the current movement (if any) before engaging the player in the new one?

Comment: I'm fairly new to AS3, so I have no idea how to do that but I'm sure I'll figure it out! Haha... pray for me.

Comment: In the essence, you can subscribe the same method to the same event as many times as you want (then later you will need to unsubscribe it as many times to completely cancel the subscription). So, you subscribe to ENTER_FRAME once - the subscribed function is triggered once per frame. Subscribe 2 times - twice per frame, and so on.